# Why is this not a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It's been a while since I took abstract algebra but I'm wondering what is wrong with my reasoning here

A group $(G, \circ)$ is defined as a tuple that consists of a set $G$ along with an operation $\circ: G \times G \to G$ such that the following conditions are satisfied

1. (Closure) For all $a,b \in G$, $a \circ b \in G$
2. (Associativity) For all $a,b,c \in G$, $(a \circ b) \circ c = a \circ (b \circ c)$
3. (Identity) There is an element $1_G \in G$ such that $a \circ 1_G = 1_G \circ a = a$ for all $a \in G$
4. (Inverse) For all $a \in G$, there is an element $a' \in G$ such that $a \circ a' = a' \circ a = 1_G$

Now, as far as I know, the uniqueness of the identity and inverse are not axioms of the group definition.

So now consider the following:
Let $G = \{1_G, a, b, c, d\}$ and define the operation $\circ$ such that $a \circ b = 1_G$ for all $a,b$

---

My question now is whether $(G,\circ)$ is a group. Simple algebra can show that in fact $a = b = c = d = 1_G$ which makes sense since $(\{1\}, \cdot)$ is a group where $1 \cdot 1 = 1$.

---

But the fact that $a = b = c = d = 1_G$ doesn't make sense to me since $a,b,c,d$ could be anything. At its core, $G$ is a set and I might as well have written $G = \{1_G, \text{horse}, \text{monkey}, \text{dog}, \text{cat}\}$ with the earlier specified operation.

If $G$ is looked at as just a set with no other structure, then clearly $\text{monkey} \neq \text{horse}$ but somehow now if you combine it with an operation, then suddenly $\text{monkey} = \text{horse}$? Or is something else going on here that I seem to have forgotten...

Comment: "Simple algebra can show that in fact $a=b=c=d=1_{G}$" What simple algebra is that? Whatever steps you did likely assumed that $G$ was already a group to begin with. If you define $G$ as you do, and tacitly assume that $a$ through $d$ are distinct, then $G,\circ$ is not a group.

Comment: I can define any operation I like orthogonal to the actual set. So I can always just create an operator $\circ$ such that $\text{monkey} \circ \text{horse} = 1_G$ and similarly for others. Before the operation, I just have a set. After I add this operation, all of the properties of the group seem to be obeyed but this operation implicitly forces the group to just be the identity group

Comment: To show $a = b$, we can just say $a \circ c = 1_G = b \circ c$ (by definition of $\circ$) and now multiply by $c'$ (inverse of $c$) to get $a \circ (c \circ c') = b \circ (c  \circ c')$ i.e. $a \circ 1_G = b \circ 1_G$ i.e. $a = b$.

Comment: Your definition of a group is wrong. The identity condition is $a\circ1_G=1_G\circ a=a$. You left out the all-important "$=a$".

Comment: My bad. But that still shouldn't change anything

Comment: @Adam it clearly does, for now $a\circ1_{G}:=1_{G}\neq a$.

Comment: Ah makes sense @Eric

Comment: Thanks all. I realized what I ended up constructing is called the [Null Semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_semigroup)

Answer (score 2):

"...since $a,b,c,d$ could be anything." What you just concluded is that this claim is false if $(G,\circ)$ is indeed a group (that is, if $(G,\circ)$ is a group, then we must have $a = b = c = d = 1_G$ necessarily, no other choices). If it isn't then of course it can be anything else, like you said horse, monkey etc.

In other words, should you insist that $a,b,c,d$ are distinct objects, then $(G,\circ)$ can't be a group.

Answer (score 2):

If $G$ is a group then for all $g\in G$ we have that $gG=G=Gg$. However, in your example you have that $gG=\{1_G\}$, so this is not a group (it is a semigroup though). You should think of the elements in your set/group as constants, and so they are implicitly non-equal and cannot be "anything".

The property that "for all $g\in G$, $gG=G=Gg$" actually almost characterises groups. You additionally need $G$ to be non-empty. So a  group is the same as a nonempty set with an associative binary operation $\cdot :G\times G\rightarrow G$ called multiplication such that for any $g\in G$, the operations of left and right multiplication by g are bijections. This characterisation leads to the idea of the "empty group", and there is a recent $n$-category cafe post about this [here](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2020/08/the_group_with_no_elements.html#more) (from which I stole the above definition).